# How to design a pixel-perfect progress ring that works for all browser zoom levels?

Tags: html, css, subpixel

My issue is not with the progress ring itself, you can see the attached snippet as an example. It works as expected, and exactly as I need it, but not for all browser zoom levels. At some levels, the size of the inner circle and/or the spacing between the ring and the inner circle is not pixel-perfect. You can clearly see that at certain browser zoom levels, there's less spacing between the ring and the inner circle.

Here's a demonstration of the problem as a GIF:

[image]

Is there anything that can be done to fix this across all browsers?

```css
:root {
  --ring-size: 26px;
  --border-width: 2px;
  --progress: 75%;
  --gap-size: 1px;
}

html {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.progressRing {
  width: var(--ring-size);
  height: var(--ring-size);
  background: conic-gradient(red var(--progress), lightgray 0);
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}

.progressRing::before {
  content: "";
  width: calc(100% - var(--border-width) * 2);
  height: calc(100% - var(--border-width) * 2);
  margin: auto;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
}

.innerCircle {
  width: calc(100% - var(--border-width) * 2 - var(--gap-size) * 2);
  height: calc(100% - var(--border-width) * 2 - var(--gap-size) * 2);
  background-color: gray;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Progress Ring</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="progressRing">
    <div class="innerCircle"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: SVG should do i guess ?

Comment: It seems to be a rounding subpixel issue as you tagged. Maybe you'd get better results if you applied a radial gradient to get gray/white/transparent bands on the same element where you have the conical gradient, without using the extra positioned child element.

Comment: Or use nice rounded numbers in your initial CSS that multiply to whole pixels most of the time.

Comment: SVG is most definitely the best option - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/yLgzpXm

Comment: @G-Cyrillus I tried SVG before, and it had the same problem.

Comment: @prkos Also did an implementation with a gradient, and it exhibited the same issue. Not sure what you mean with the second comment.

Comment: @Paulie_D Interesting, that seems to work, but my current SVG solution exhibits the same problem. I'll have it to compare to yours, and see where it's failing.

Answer (score 0):

I got a pretty good result using the radial gradient instead of an extra child element and the pseudoelement.

Using the calc technique where you "move" the points that are of the same color half a pixel or full pixel away is what is making the color transitions smooth and also fully centered.

```css
:root {
  --ring-size: 26px;
  --border-width: 2px;
  --progress: 75%;
  --gap-size: 2px;
}

html {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.progressRing {
  width: var(--ring-size);
  height: var(--ring-size);
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at center, silver 0, silver calc(50% - (var(--border-width) + var(--gap-size)) - 1px), white calc(50% - (var(--border-width) + var(--gap-size))), white calc(50% - var(--border-width) - 1px), transparent calc(50% - var(--border-width))), conic-gradient(red var(--progress), lightgray 0);
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Progress Ring</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="progressRing">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```